# como eliminar una fila de un gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, gridview, datatable

tengo 2 gridview en una pagina, el primero se llena desde una base de datos y el segundo lo lleno con las filas que selecciono en un checkbox,
en cada fila del gridview tengo un boton enlazado con un metodo para eliminar esa fila en particular

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantidad" DataField="Cantidad"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo" DataField="IdProducto"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Marca" DataField="NomMarca"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ciudad" DataField="NomCiudad"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tamaño" DataField="Tamano"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fragilidad" DataField="NomFragilidad"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ubicacion" DataField="NomUbicacion"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Proveedor" DataField="NomProveedor"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Producto" DataField="NomProducto"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion" DataField="Descripcion"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Existencias" DataField="Existencias"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Precio de Venta" DataField="PrecioVenta"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Precio de Compra" DataField="PrecioCompra"/>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button id="btn_eliminar"  OnClick="btn_eliminar_Click" runat="server" Text="Eliminar" Enabled="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

cuando necesito eliminar una fila en particular del gridview2 el metodo que hice al principio se comporta bien, pero cuando quedan 1 o 2 filas ya no elimina mas filas.

necesito eliminar esas filas solo del gridview no de la base de datos, para que el usuario una vez que este seguro inserte los datos en otra tabla de la base de datos.
si necesitan que muestre otras partes del codigo solo pidanmelo, de antemano muchas gracias!

```
protected void btn_eliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    int indexdeboton = gvr.RowIndex;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["GetRecords"];
    dt.Rows[indexdeboton].Delete();
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```